# How to run @Beforesuite and @Aftersuite once for parallel execution

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests

I my case, I need to run parallel tests. I am using the hooks called @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite. Both parallel executions must give one @BeforeSuite and one @AfterSuite result. However, I am getting results up to the number of parallel runs. How can I solve this problem?